# populating a ListView from separate sql tables

Tags: android, sql, listview

What I am trying to do is populate one listview, from two different tables in my database.  The tables that I am using are:

```
--------------------------
|UNIT_TABLE|SHOVEL_TABLE |
|ID        |ID           |
|SITE_NAME |SITE_NAME    |
|UNIT_NAME |SHOVEL_NAME  |
--------------------------
```

The id is used in all my tables, as a basic autoincrement not null, the SITE_NAME is the name of the where the UNIT_TABLE and SHOVEL_TABLE are being completed at.

After some research on the best option I decided to use the following code to create a join on the two tables using the SITE_NAME to determine which ones I need.

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    String[] queries=new String[]{"select "+ID+", "+SHOVEL_NAME+" from "+SHOVEL_TABLE+" where "+SITE_NAME+"='"+Site+"'",
            "select "+ID+", "+ UNIT_NAME+" from "+UNIT_TABLE+" where "+SITE_NAME+"='"+Site+"'"};
    String SQL= qb.buildUnionQuery(queries, null, null);
```

This allowed me to combine all the data into one table, and populate my listview using a SimpleCursorAdapter.  However, when I click on a list item, it takes me to the same activity.  What I need it to do is if the item came from the SHOVEL_TABLE to go one Shovel.class, and if it came from the UNIT_TABLE I need it to go Unit.class.

Looking for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume that you use an adapter in populating your listview right?, den i guess in your adapter, you can put added info for your listitemlistener to take note on.

Comment: like for example, in your, say you define your own list_item.xml for your adapter to use, you can put a hidden textview for you to put a marker so that when u put a itemclicklistener, you will know where to go

Comment: Thank you for the response, I think I understand what you are saying.  I have altered my code and layout, so that I have an extra variable that is being passed: u=unit, and s=shovel.  They pass to the OnListItemClick, but there I can not get a control structure to work to read what they are.  Can you have a control structure inside of an OnListItemClick?  I understand, that that maybe a separate question to ask in a seperate thread.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it at least helped move me forward, thank  you.

Comment: if control structure u mean, if s = shovel and stuff then yes

Comment: by the way to access the clicked view on your item, just access the view being pass on the method overriden in your listener